# "Unable to start Minecraft Runtime Enviroment"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

A couple of days ago I tried getting on Minecraft with a friend. They were running 1.14.2, and my Minecraft was last updated to 1.14. No big deal; I'll just create a new instance in 1.14.2.

When I did this, it said the latest version was 1.14. It said - I cannot remember how exactly - that it could not obtain versions, and on the news page it said I was offline when I clearly was not.

I decided to try and reinstall Minecraft.

So I went to the Windows uninstaller and uninstalled everything having to do with Minecraft. I then installed the Minecraft installer and installed Minecraft.
That was when I got the message "*Unable to start Minecraft Runtime Environment, this is most likely caused by corruption. Please reinstall Minecraft*".

I tried using the repair function in the installer to no avail.
So I tried going into `%appdata%` and manually removing the `.minecraft` folder, and also going to `Program Files (x86)` and removing anything with Minecraft in its name.
Then I reinstalled the installer, and tried again, but the issue recurred.
At that point, I searched the internet for fixes, and found and tried all of the following, followed by trying the installer again:

- Running everything as admin;
- Removing `.minecraft` (despite already having done this);
- Making sure I'd got the right version of Java;
- Reinstalling Java;
- Trying [the older version of the launcher](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.exe) (when I tried this, the entire console was blank and it basically did nothing. I checked the log and everything - I'll provide the logs at the end of this post).

---

System specifications:

(Hardware capable of running things like GTA V)

```
Windows 10.0.17763 
Java version : jre1.8.0_211
Native log under %appdata% > .minecraft:

     Native Launcher Version: 432
            Operating System: Windows 10 Home
  Application Data directory: C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft
             Executable Path: MinecraftLauncher.exe
           App Directory dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft Launcher
         Game data directory: C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft
                Launcher dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft Launcher\game
                    Java dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft Launcher\runtime\jre-x64
                  TmpDir dir: C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\MinecraftLauncher
                         x64: 1
 Using configuration at path: C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\launcher_profiles.json

    Could not get manifest from piston backend.
    Starting C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft Launcher\game\launcher.dll with 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft Launcher\runtime\jre-x64\bin\javaw.exe
    Couldn't load launcher core from 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft Launcher\game\launcher.dll: LoadErrorNotPresent
```

Log of the older launcher:

```
    [18:41:30 INFO]: Minecraft Launcher 1.6.89-j (through bootstrap 5) started on windows...
    [18:41:30 INFO]: Current time is Jun 12, 2019 6:41:30 PM
    [18:41:30 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Windows 10'
    [18:41:30 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.version') == '10.0'
    [18:41:30 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'amd64'
    [18:41:30 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.8.0_211'
    [18:41:30 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
    [18:41:30 INFO]: System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '64'
    [18:41:30 INFO]: proxy == DIRECT
    [18:41:30 INFO]: JFX is already initialized
    [18:41:31 INFO]: Refreshing local version list...
    [18:41:31 INFO]: Refreshing remote version list...
    [18:41:31 ERROR]: Unexpected exception refreshing version list
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at com.mojang.launcher.Http.performGet(Http.java:54) ~[launcher.jar:1.6.89-j]
        at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.RemoteVersionList.getContent(RemoteVersionList.java:60) ~[launcher.jar:1.6.89-j]
        at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.RemoteVersionList.refreshVersions(RemoteVersionList.java:42) ~[launcher.jar:1.6.89-j]
        at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.MinecraftVersionManager.refreshVersions(MinecraftVersionManager.java:62) ~[launcher.jar:1.6.89-j]
        at net.minecraft.launcher.Launcher$2.run(Launcher.java:177) [launcher.jar:1.6.89-j]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        ... 23 more
    [18:41:31 INFO]: Loaded 1 profile(s); selected 'jamesadam10'
    [18:41:31 INFO]: Refreshing auth...
    [18:41:31 INFO]: Logging in with access token
```

**UPDATE:**
I tried installing Minecraft on my laptop from the same site, and I got the exact same issue, leading me to believe that the site I used is dodgy. I'm going to try to find the proper site and see if that works. If it does, I will post about it, and I will include the website's address so that no one else has this issue.

Comment: I fixed some basic grammar at the beginning and removed unnecessary bits at the end. Can you please do the same with the rest of the text and remove some more filler? If you have more information, just write it in the question. Also, you should put the log into a code block with the `{ }` button.

Comment: thankyou, i will go and do that

Comment: SSL cert errors like that can also be caused by wrong clock settings. Is your PC time correct?

Comment: as far as i can tell the computer is automatically updating the time from time.windows.com, so i'd assume so

Answer (score 1):

Restart your computer then start the launcher again.

I guess the installer should include a warning about unfinished installation and that a reboot is required...